# Meteor-1.6 does not support deprecated CFS:gridFS

Tags: image, meteor, gridfs, multipart-alternative

Just updated to Meteor JS 1.6 and the deprecated cfs:gridfs throws this error, what's the workaround? Any better alternatives if this will not work with Meteor-1.6.

```
 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While checking for cfs:gridfs@0.0.33:
   error: No compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the package author and ask them to publish it
   for your platform.
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error. I've tried with " meteor add cfs:gridfs." By any chance did you solve it?

Comment: @Supradip.M what I resolved was to use the ```cfs:filesystem```, that solved the issue.

Comment: Does gridfs work after doing this?